# How do I use the same MySQL connection(s) for my entire Node.js app?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have an `app.js`. I run my entire app from there.

Inside app.js, I `require` many files that have code in it.

For each of these files, I do this:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var mclient = mysql.createConnection({
    host: settings.MYSQL.HOST,
    user: settings.MYSQL.USER,
    password: settings.MYSQL.PASSWORD,
    database: settings.MYSQL.DB,
});
```

Essentially, I am initiating a new connection for every file.

I want my app.js to make ONE connection, and then pass it to every file during the require line.  How can I pass the connection to them so those files can use it?

(Or how can I pass a pool of connections to them?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a separate module, call it `mysqlLib.js` that will be responsible for creating a pool and returning connections:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var pool = mysql.createPool(/* credentials go here */);

exports.getConnection = function(callback) {
  pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
    if(err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    callback(err, conn);
  });
};
```

and in any module/file that needs a mysql connection, you can do this:

```
var mysqlLib = require("mysqlLib");

mysqlLib.getConnection(function(err, mclient) {
  //do queries that you need
});
```

The way `require()` works, the code in `mysqlLib.js` will only be run once so only one pool will be created even if `require("mysqlLib.js"}` is called in multiple files.  See [this section](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) of the node.js docs for an explanation of module cacheing.

Comment: Why would it only run once?

Comment: @TIMEX: I updated my answer with a link to the node.js docs that explain the "load only once" thing.

Comment: @go-oleg I am trying to implement this method of connection you posted and am having some trouble. I have a bunch of methods attached via `module.exports.someFunctionName = function(){   }` and I've been sending queries through a variable like this `connectionVariable.query("sql statement");` So I'm wondering how to send that query inside the `mysqlLib.getConnection` function you posted... Is it something like `pool.query("sql statement");` or is that wrong?

Comment: I want to test it but I just have so much attached to these snippets that I am afraid of making a huge change, running the risk of a bunch of errors popping up.

Comment: Or would It be the second parameter you passed, the `mclient` that i would attach the `.query()` to?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the `mclient` to attach your query

```
var mysqlLib = require("mysqlLib");

mysqlLib.getConnection(function(err, mclient) {
  //do queries that you need
  var sql = '//Your SQL here';
  var inserts = [your inserts here];
  sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);
  mclient.query(sql, function (err, rows) {

  if (err) {
                //handle error here
            }

  })
});
```