# Initialize a mysql pool in app and reuse in modules

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am new to node and try to get a good design pattern for my app.
I made a module to create a pool

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'host',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'pwd',
  database : 'db'
});

exports.pool = pool;
```

This I can reuse in my module by requiring:

```
var db = require('./db').pool;
```

Now I would like to set the options for the pool in app.js, something in the module like:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool  = mysql.createPool(options);

exports.pool = pool;
```

... in app.js I would initially have to set up this pool with:

```
ar options = {...}

var db = require('./db').pool(options);
```

But this does not work. What am I thinking wrong?

Comment: This solved my question

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598430/how-do-i-use-the-same-mysql-connections-for-my-entire-node-js-app][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598430/how-do-i-use-the-same-mysql-connections-for-my-entire-node-js-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following pattern to initialise your pool once, then easily reference it through the rest of your application:

**db.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports = {
    init: function(name, options) {
        return module.exports[name] = mysql.createPool(options);
    }
};
```

**app.js**

```
var options = {...}
var db = require('./db').init("pool1", options); // initialise once
```

**something-else.js**

```
var db = require('./db').pool1; // references the pool created in app.js
```

You could then also create other pools for other databases.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want `require('./db').pool` to refer to a factory function that creates your pool.

Change your db.js to something like:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

exports.pool = function(options){
    return mysql.createPool(options);
};
```

Then you'll be able to pass in your options from `app.js` as you already do:

```
var options = {...}
var db = require('./db').pool(options);
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. But this does not persist throughout appending modules. If I call the pool from another file, the options are lost. What is the best strategy to handle mysql in an app which does not consist only a single file. Creating a new pool in every module (or file) seems inefficient. Any hints?

Comment: Init once and reference throughout? A bit like a service provider pattern? I'll create a new answer in a minute.